# $routeParams empty when hiting specific route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have something like this

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'languages',
    suffix: '.json'
  });
}]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/something/:test', {controller: 'mainController'});
}]);
regFormAppControllers.controller('mainController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http, $modal,$routeParams) {
    var initRoute = function () {
      console.log($routeParams);
        if ($routeParams.test) {
          console.log("asdasdsadasd");
        }
    });
```

I loaded angular router in html and I have dependency loaded with ngRoute,

now when i hit in my browser `http://localhost/testApp/index.html#something/:2` it refresh page but this console.log($routeParams) is empty. I need to call a function in main controller when user hit specific route. How to do this?

Comment: Usually, the : in the url is used when defining the route, but in the actual URL. What happens if you try and hit something/2

Comment: Looks like you're just defining a function `initRoute` but I don't see any code that is actually calling it